# Unable use OAuth2 with Honeywell API to control Thermostat, Authorized Flow Code vs Client Credentials?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

If I use their developer website, I plug in my API key and it authenticates OAuth2, and I can copy and paste the bearer token ('access_token') straight into my python script and I am able to control the thermostat.

However, when I try to generate the access_token myself, it appears to work fine, but I am unable to use it.

I'm confused, its something about OAuth2 Authorized Flow Code vs OAuth2 Client Credentials I guess?
There is a reference to using "UserRefID" in headers when using Client Credentials, but I have not seen that variable in any responses, nor in any other documentation?

```
def gettemp():
    bearer = get_token()
        
    url = f"https://api.honeywell.com/v2/devices/thermostats/{deviceId}"
    params = {
        "apikey": client_id,  #this is the consumer key provided by honeywell (risideo)
        "locationId": mylocationid
     }

    headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer}",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "api.honeywell.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    code = response.status_code
    print(response.text)
    indoor = response.json()['indoorTemperature']
    outdoor = response.json()['outdoorTemperature']
```

if I place the bearer statically above from the website it works, until the token times out.
the code below gets me a new token, but it never works

```
def get_token():
    auth_header = base64.b64encode(f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'.encode()).decode()
    
    token_url = 'https://api.honeywell.com/oauth2/accesstoken'
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Basic {auth_header}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(f'bearer response is {response}')
    bearer = response.json()['access_token']
    return bearer
```

this is the response from get_token:

```
 "refresh_token_expires_in": "0",
 "api_product_list": "[Basic Development Plan]",
 "api_product_list_json": [
"Basic Development Plan"
 ],
 "organization_name": "connectedhome",
 "developer.email": "thermostat@gmail.com",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "issued_at": "1691280024096",
 "client_id": "shO6XG34OyRbEwFgaOtgFpqPmqAHSZlg",
 "access_token": "UbxWbkZEAVGfbb7uGXvACcr34Wv4",
 "application_name": "6f54cdb4-4d27-4b95-ae39-d8d5db36ad83",
 "scope": "",
 "expires_in": "3599",
 "refresh_count": "0",
 "status": "approved"
```

and the response from using that token in gettemp():

```
 "code": "Unauthorized",
 "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request  "
```

Comment: Do you get any error response? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: sorry, added. 401 unauthorized when i use my token, or when the one from the website expires

Comment: There's some code missing, like your urls and params in gettemp. Also you print the full bearer response, is it approved? Example `"status": "approved"` in the returned dictionary.

Comment: edited to add them in